# SELECT query from field having multiple value with WHERE_IN clause

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, view, where-in

The following is a VIEW **search_result**.  `skills` column contains the values that are **GROUP_CONCAT** with values in some other table.

[image: search_result VIEW]

Now I'm trying to select values from this VIEW with a **where_in** clause like this:

```
$s_id = array('2D Design','3D Design');

$this->db->select('id');
$this->db->from('search_result');
$this->db->where_in('skills',$s_id);
```

On executing this query the result is only 3 rows i.e skills which contains only **2D Design** or **2D Design**.

[image: result on executing same query in phpmyadmin]

I want to display all those rows which contain any of that skills as output. So please help me to do this.

Comment: Try using `LIKE` operator

Comment: @viki888 thanks for your comment. The below answer works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to use `FIND_IN_SET` here:

```
$s_id = array('2D Design','3D Design');

$this->db->select('id');
$this->db->from('search_result');
$this->db->where("FIND_IN_SET('$s_id[0]', skills) != ", 0);

for($x=1; $x < count($s_id); $x++) {
    $this->db->or_where("FIND_IN_SET('$s_id[$x]', skills) != ", 0);
}
```

The logic here is that you effectively want to use `FIND_IN_SET` on *each* skill in your array to see if it be contained within the CSV list of skills in your table.  You can't do this with a single call, and each check should be ORed together in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: what if I remove the where clause and change `$x=0` inside the for loop?

Comment: @Shihas This _might_ work, depending on the behavior of `or_where`.  If it can be called without first calling `where()` then it might be OK.  Otherwise, stick with the code I gave you.